# Deserializing Avro message

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I deployed Kafka from [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.4.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml). Also I added to `docker-compose.yml` Postgres container like this:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres
    hostname: kafka-postgres
    container_name: kafka-postgres
    depends_on:
      - ksql-server
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Created a topic pageviews.

Further I created DatagenConnector with settings and ran it.

```
{
  "name": "datagen-pageviews",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "kafka.topic": "pageviews",
  "max.interval": "100",
  "iterations": "999999999",
  "quickstart": "pageviews"
}
```

As far as I can see the connector defined a schema for the topic:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "pageviews",
  "namespace": "ksql",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "viewtime",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "userid",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "pageid",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "connect.name": "ksql.pageviews"
}
```

My next step was to create JdbcSinkConnector that would transfer data from Kafka topic to Postgres table. That worked. The settings of connector:

```
{
  "name": "from-kafka-to-pg",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "errors.log.enable": "true",
  "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
  "topics": [
    "pageviews"
  ],
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://kafka-postgres:5432/postgres",
  "connection.user": "postgres",
  "connection.password": "********",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "auto.evolve": "true"
}
```

Then I try to send messages to that topic by myself. But failed with error:

> [2020-02-01 21:16:11,750] ERROR Error encountered in task to-pg-0.
>   Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class
>   'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter', where consumed record is
>   {topic='pageviews', partition=0, offset=23834,
>   timestamp=1580591160374, timestampType=CreateTime}.
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize
>   data for topic pageviews to Avro:     at
>   io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
>   deserializing Avro message for id -1 Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic
>   byte!

So the send method matters. This is how I do this (Python, confluent-kafka-python):

```
producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
producer.poll(0)
producer.produce(topic, json.dumps({
   'viewtime': 123,
   'userid': 'user_1',
   'pageid': 'page_1'
}).encode('utf8'), on_delivery=kafka_delivery_report)
producer.flush()
```

Maybe should I provide a schema with message (AvroProducer)?

Comment: Which library are you using? `kafka-python` or `confluent-kafka-python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic expects a message in Avro type.

[`AvroProducer`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) from [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) does the trick:

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer


value_schema_str = """
{
   "namespace": "ksql",
   "name": "value",
   "type": "record",
   "fields" : [
     {
       "name" : "viewtime",
       "type" : "long"
     }, 
     {
       "name" : "userid",
       "type" : "string"
     }, 
     {
       "name" : "pageid",
       "type" : "string"
     }
   ]
}
"""

key_schema_str = """
{
   "namespace": "ksql",
   "name": "key",
   "type": "record",
   "fields" : [
     {
       "name" : "pageid",
       "type" : "string"
     }
   ]
}
"""

value_schema = avro.loads(value_schema_str)
key_schema = avro.loads(key_schema_str)
value = {"name": "Value"}
key = {"name": "Key"}


def delivery_report(err, msg):
    """ Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
        Triggered by poll() or flush(). """
    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {} [{}]'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))


avroProducer = AvroProducer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'mybroker,mybroker2',
    'on_delivery': delivery_report,
    'schema.registry.url': 'http://schema_registry_host:port'
    }, default_key_schema=key_schema, default_value_schema=value_schema)

avroProducer.produce(topic='my_topic', value=value, key=key)
avroProducer.flush()
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot.
Does it double the message size?

Comment: @АльбертАлександров No it does not. Why it would?

Comment: Well, this is my misunderstanding. But thanks to you I became to understand more than yesterday.

Comment: Sure.
So, assuming. 
Every single producer defines the data schema he sends to topic. And another producer who produces data to the same topic can define another (but compatible only) schema. Right? 
Earlier I thought that I must define topic schema in Control Center and to use it in code.

Comment: Your schema version and compatibility should be managed through Schema Registry.

Comment: I changed the schema in code, produced a message and the schema was renewed in registry as new version.

Comment: You need to set schema compatibility accordingly. https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arises because you try to use the *Avro converter* to read data from a topic that is *not Avro*.

There are two possible solutions:

*1. Switch Kafka Connect’s sink connector to use the correct converter*

For example, if you’re consuming JSON data from a Kafka topic into a Kafka Connect sink:

```
...
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter. 
value.converter.schemas.enable=true/false
...
```

`value.converter.schemas.enable` depends on whether the message contains a schema..

*2. Switch the upstream format to Avro*

For DatagenConnector to produce messages to Kafka where the message value format is `Avro`, set the `value.converter` and `value.converter.schema.registry.url` parameters:

```
...
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
...
```

See kafka-connect-datagen [docs](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen#confusion-about-schemas-and-avro) for details.

---

Great [article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/) on Kafka Connect Converters and Serialization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links. 
It seems that I don't understand what Avro topic is. Does that mean that I should use confluent_kafka.avro.AvroProducer instead of simple Producer?
If so there are some additional questions appear. I described a schema for topic pageviews in Control Center and it is in a list in api endpoint http://0.0.0.0:8081/subjects/ (name: pageviews-value). And now I should duplicate it so I could provide the schema with a message when sending to Kafka topic?